# Git rebase branch with all parent branches (or dependent sub-branches)

Tags: git, branch, rebase, git-rebase

Is it possible to rebase a branch with all its parent branches with Git? (I think "parent branches" is the correct form to use here. Depending on your viewpoint, you might also call them dependent sub-branches. Yet, following the parent-pointers of the commits will get you to those branches, so IMHO it is fair to call them "parent branches").

I often use branches as quick/mutable tags/checkpoints to mark certain commits.
All parent branches/parent refs are fully included in the branch-to-be-rebased; there are no commits only in the parent branches.

```
* master
*
* featureA-finished
*
* origin/master
```

Now I want to `rebase -i` `master` onto `origin/master` to change/reword the commit `featureA-finished^`

After `git rebase -i --onto origin/master origin/master master`, I basically want the history to be:

```
* master
*
* featureA-finished
* (changed/reworded)
* origin/master
```

but what I get is:

```
* master
*
* (same changeset as featureA-finished)
* (changed/reworded)
| * featureA-finished
|.* (original commit i wanted to edit)
* origin/master
```

is there a way around it, or am I stuck with recreating all parent branches – more specifically the branch labels – on the new, rebased commits?

This question is related to, but still very different from [Rebasing a branch including all its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600659/rebasing-a-branch-including-all-its-children).

Comment: You could instead of branches use `git notes` to mark your commits - those are automatically copied along during rebases, I believe. (It's a new feature, so you'll need the latest release) http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-notes.html

Comment: See also [how I'd rebase a whole subhistory -- several branches, with some links between them resulting from merge](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9706495/94687). 

The unpleasant part of that solution is the need to reset the topic branch refs to the new rebased commits afterwards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like this feature is slowly getting into Git. `rebase` will gain the option `--rebase-refs` which will do exactly what my original answer asked. For the proposed patch series see the thread [rebase: command "ref" and options --rewrite-{refs,heads,tags}](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/176339) on gmane.

---

Update 2022:

The option [`--update-refs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---update-refs) has finally landed in Git v2.38.0, which can now do exactly what was asked in the initial question more than 12 years ago :)

This feature was merged with commit [3d8e3dc4fc22fe41f8ee1184f085c600f35ec76f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3d8e3dc4fc22fe41f8ee1184f085c600f35ec76f) in August. Hooray!

Comment: It's a pity this seems not to have got into Git: I haven't seen such a feature in the current documentation (manpage) for git-rebase! (git-1.7.9.3)

Answer (score 5):

According to git's [Object Model](http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html) if you only change the meta-data of a commit (i.e. commit message) but not the underlying data ("tree(s)") contained within it then it's Tree hash will remain unchanged.

Aside from editing a commit message, you are also performing a rebase, which will change the Tree hashes of each commit in your history, because any changes pulled from `origin/master` will affect the files in your re-written history: which means some of the files (blobs) that your commit points to have changed.

So there is no bullet-proof way to do what you want.

That said, editing a commit with `rebase -i` does not usually alter the commit's timestamp and author, so you could use this to uniquely identify your commits before and after a rebase operation.

You would have to write a script which records all the branch start-points against these "timestamp:author" identifier before doing a rebase, and then find the rewritten commits with the same "timestamp:author" ID and rebase the branch on it.

Sadly, I don't have time to try writing this script myself now, so I can only wish you the best of luck!

**Edit**: You can obtain the author email address and timestamp using:

```
$ git log --graph --all --pretty=format:"%h %ae:%ci"
* 53ca31a robert.meerman@gmail.com:2010-06-16 13:50:12 +0100
* 03dda75 robert.meerman@gmail.com:2010-06-16 13:50:11 +0100
| * a8bb03a robert.meerman@gmail.com:2010-06-16 13:49:46 +0100
| * b93e59d robert.meerman@gmail.com:2010-06-16 13:49:44 +0100
|/
* d4214a2 robert.meerman@gmail.com:2010-06-16 13:49:41 +0100
```

And you can obtain a list of branches for each of these based on their commit hash:

```
$ git branch --contains 03dda75
* testbranch
```

Watch out for multiple branches per commit, the common ancestor `d4214a2` belongs to both branches!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how exactly you got there, but:

```
git branch -f (same changeset as featureA-finished)
```

should be enough to reset your `featureA-finished` branch with the right history.

Comment: yes, that's what i meant with »recreating the branches on the new rebased commits«. i know it is possible this way, but it gets really cumbersome for three branches already

Comment: @knittl: interesting. A more detail log diagram of those branches before and after might help here.

Comment: just imagine the same graph with 15 commits, every second commit being featureA-finished, featureB-finished, featureC-finished, etc.

Answer (score 1):

What I'd advise is to rebase `featureA-finished` onto `origin/master` first.  Do the rewording step then.  After that, rebase `master` onto `featureA-finished`.  This will net you the end result you are wanting.

Note that you'll need to use `-i` on both rebases, and may have to delete all the commits from the original `featureA-finshed` down in the second rebase.  If you wanted, you could write a script that would eliminate this by saving off the intermediate branch and using that as the base for a rebase `--onto` the new version.  It could even handle a sequence of such 'subbranches' if you wrote it right.  If you need help I can attempt to bang one out.