# Git rebase subtree

Tags: git, branch, rebase

Suppose I have the following scenario:

```
    o (master)   
   /       o--o (WIP1)
  /       /
 o--o--o--o--o--o (WIP2)
(X)       \
           o--o (WIP3)
```

Is there a git command which creates a new branch so that it contains the subtree after branch X? I want to perform a "large rebase", I want the three WIP branches rebased on master.

I know I can do that with some Bash scripting but I'd like to know how to do that using a git command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rebasing a branch including all its children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600659/rebasing-a-branch-including-all-its-children)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rebasing a tree (a commit/branch and all its children)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315285/rebasing-a-tree-a-commit-branch-and-all-its-children)

Answer (score 16):

There is no single git command for that. You will have to do some manual work. In your situation:

```
    o (master)   
   /        o--o (WIP1)
  /        /
 X--o--o--B--o--o (WIP2)
           \
            o--o (WIP3)
```

You first rebase WIP1 onto master:

```
git rebase --onto master X WIP1
```

which will lead to this:

```
               o--o (WIP1)
 (master)     /
    o--o--o--B’
   /   
  /        
 X--o--o--B--o--o (WIP2)
           \
            o--o (WIP3)
```

If you now run `git rebase --onto master X WIP2`, you get this structure:

```
                o--o (WIP1)
 (master)      /
     o--o--o--B’
    / \
   /   o--o--B’’--o--o (WIP2)
  /        
 X--o--o--B--o--o (WIP3)
```

This is probably not what you want, so now you should rebase WIP2 and WIP3 on `B’`:

```
git rebase --onto B’ B WIP2 
git rebase --onto B’ B WIP3
```

which will lead to this:

```
                  o--o (WIP1)
(master)         /
    o--X--o--o--B’--o--o (WIP2)
                 \
                  o--o (WIP3)
```

Comment: Yes, saw your edit just prior to submitting, but by then I had already drawn all that ascii-art ^^

Comment: I had to upvote for the step-by-step ascii charts. Good answer. Why didn't either of the answers ever get the check mark, @cd1?

Comment: What about rebase in a more complex way with merge commits?

Answer (score 3):

I have flagged this question as duplicate. I will write what I explained 
[the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315285/rebasing-a-tree-a-commit-branch-and-all-its-children/45844847) but using your example.

The approach that I use for such use cases is to merge all the branches 
to be moved into 1 *common artificial* node, and then use the rebase command
with the `--preserve-merges` option. Merging all the branches will **expose 1
end-point** that will be used as the final input parameter for `rebase --onto`. The
start point is usually obvious, the origin of the subtree to move.

When merging to get the *subtree endpoint*, conflicts should be explicity
avoided. Therefore the merge commands shall be instructed to solve them
automatically with the `-Xours` option. The merging result is not important
since these *artificial* merge nodes will be discarded after the rebase.

It is recommended to create a new branch *pack* in order to not lose the
original references. In the example above the following commands would be
performed:

```
$ git checkout -b pack WIP1 # create new branch at 'WIP1'
$ git merge -s recursive -Xours WIP2 # merges WIP2 into pack (node p2)
$ git merge -s recursive -Xours WIP3 # merges WIP3 into pack
```

Below can be seen what the tree would become. Two new *artificial* nodes
*p2* and *pack* have been created with the merges.

```
      o (master)
     /
    /          (WIP1)  (p2)
   /        o-----o-----o----o (pack)
  /        /           /    /
 o--o--o--o-----o-----o    / (WIP2)
(X)        \              /
            o------------o (WIP3)
```

Now it's time to rebase. Since now there is a common endpoint for all the
branches (*pack*), it's easy to move the whole subtree with:

```
$ git rebase --preserve-merges --onto master X pack
```

Which produces this:

```
                      (WIP1') (p2')
                   o-----o-----o----o (pack')
   (master)       /           /    /
 o----o----o--o--o-----o-----o    / (WIP2')
(X)               \              /
                   o------------o (WIP3')
```

Now it's time to rearrange the references. I don't know why, in some
cases the references are moved and in others are not. Type this for
each reference WIP1, WIP2, WIP3 or whatever you need:

```
$ git checkout WIP1
$ git reset --hard <WIP1' hash>
```

And finally, get rid of the *artificial* commits that were created for
generating a common subtree end node.

```
$ git branch -D pack
$ git branch -D p2 # if there is any
```

So the final tree would be:

```
                      (WIP1')
                   o-----o
   (master)       /
 o----o----o--o--o-----o-----o (WIP2')
(X)               \
                   o------------o (WIP3')
```

Comment: It's possible to streamline this a little bit by using `git rebase -i --rebase-merges`, so that you can omit the dummy merge commit at the end of the process. Discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69396585/344643

Answer (score 2):

With the [`git-branchless`](https://github.com/arxanas/git-branchless) suite of tools, you can directly rebase subtrees:

```
$ git move -b WIP1 -d master
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

---

If you want to stick with base Git, you can use the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45861361/344643), but with the new `--rebase-merges` option. Make a dummy merge-commit:

```
$ git checkout WIP1
$ git merge WIP2 WIP3
...add all conflicts and resolve...
```

And then perform the rebase interactively. The generated rebase plan will be what you want, except that you should remove the last `merge` command:

```
$ git rebase -i master --rebase-merges
...example editor contents below...
label onto

# Branch WIP1
reset abc123 
pick abc456
pick abc789
label abcdef

reset onto
pick bcd123
pick bcd456
pick bcd789

## REMOVE THIS LINE:
# merge -C abcdef
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   o (master)   
   /       o--o (WIP1)
  /       /
 o--p--p--o--o--o (WIP2)
(X)      (Y)
          \
           o--o (WIP3)
```

This should be a `rebase --onto` (you can see one example in "[How to move certain commits to another branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2369516/6309)"):

```
 git rebase --onto master X WIP1
 git rebase --onto master X WIP2
 git rebase --onto master X WIP3
```

From [Chronial](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758345/chronial)'s [test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504029/git-rebase-subtree/14504917#comment20218769_14504917), that would give:

```
         p'--p'--o--o (WIP2)
        /
 o-----o-----p--p--o--o--o (WIP1)
(X) (master)   (Y')   
        \
         p''--p''--o--o (WIP3)
```

So the first rebase is ok, but you need to get Y SHA, and:

```
 git rebase --onto Y' Y WIP2
 git rebase --onto Y' Y WIP3
```

Comment: This will create three branches that diverge off of master, won’t it? Or will this move the structure behind X on top of master (so that the branches divert later)?

Comment: @Chronial yes, there is that risk, especially considering a rebase won't replay a commit if that the same content is detected on the destination branch. I'll have to test it out.

Comment: just tested it, and they diverge :/

Comment: @Chronial Meaning the first two commits after `X` are only present in `WIP1`? And `WIP2,3` start directly from `master`?

Comment: No, the first commits after X are cloned 3 times – once for each WIP.