# git rebase with branches (whole tree)

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I am trying to connect two independent commit trees into one repository.

Initially I have:

```
A--B--C--D (master1)

E--F--G--H (master2)
   \
    I--J (somebranch)
```

These tree have no common ancestor and are independent of each other (different files and directories).
I want to rebase both master2 and somebranch (may be multiple branches in fact) onto master1.

It's easy to rebase just single branch with:

```
#simple reabse:
git checkout master2
git git rebase master1
```

which would give me:

```
A--B--C--D (master1)
          \
           E'--F'--G'--H' (master2)
E--F--G--H
   \
    I--J (somebranch)
```

Preferably I would like a single command to move both (or more) branches simultanously, to get result like this:

```
A--B--C--D (master1)
          \
           E'--F'--G'--H' (master2)
                \
                 I--J (somebranch)
```

Comment: Related: [Rebasing a branch including all its children](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5600659)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git rebase subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504029/git-rebase-subtree)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lesser-known feature called grafts to splice the histories together.

```
$ echo `git rev-list [E] -1` `git rev-list master1 -1` > .git/info/grafts
$ git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat master2 [other branches]
```

Or if there are multiple branches involved, and you don't want to have to list them all, you can do:

```
$ git filter-branch --tag-name-filter cat `git show-ref --heads | awk '{print $2}'`
```

(for more details, see [answer 161928](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161928/what-are-git-info-grafts-for), or [blog article](http://ben.straubnet.net/post/939181602/git-grafting-repositories) or [advanced instructions](http://gitolite.com/concepts/grafting.html))

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of the grafts feature, but I'm not aiming at connecting the trees, I need to rebase both master2 and somebranch onto master1.

Comment: I don't know of a variant of the `rebase` command that does what you want.

This accomplishes the same effect as using the `rebase` command (assuming they are truly independent files & directories) -- but it does it for all branches in a single command.

Comment: Issue with graft here is that commit E` after filter-branch effectively removes all files from master1 :(

Answer (score 0):

I have answered this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504029/git-rebase-subtree/45861361#45861361) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315285/rebasing-a-tree-a-commit-branch-and-all-its-children/45844847#45844847). The short answer, use rebase with the `--preserve-merges` option, but before join all branches into a common, artificial node with:

```
git checkout H
git merge -s recursive -Xours J # will generate a J2 node
```

The rebase:

```
git rebase --preserve-merges --onto D E^ J2
```

Where *E^* is the parent of *E* and *J2* the resulting node of the merge. If you use *E* instead of *E^*, node *E* won't be rebased.

See more detailed comments in the quoted posts.