# Removing a specific commit in the git history with several branches?

Tags: git, branch, commit, history, rebase

I know how to remove a specific commit from the git history with `git rebase --interactive`.

My question concerns the more complex case with a history like this:

```
A--X--B--C--D
       \
         E--F
```

where I would like to remove the commit `X`. The issue is that in this case there are two or more branches with parents (`B` in this case) that have `X` in their history, so a single `git rebase -i` will not do the trick (at least I do not know how).

Is there a simple way to remove `X`, or do I have to rely on rebasing all branches on their own, possibly with a shell script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately Git doesn't make it easy in this situation. First do an interactive rebase on the D branch by deleting commit X.

You'll have the following history:

```
A--X--B
 \     \
  \      E--F
   \
     B'-C'-D'
```

Then you'll need to rebase the F branch onto B' with:

```
git rebase --onto B' B F
```

(replace commits names by their ids)

That will end up with

```
 A--B'-C'-D'
     \
       E'--F'
```