# How do you keep branches sharing the same history through rebases?

Tags: git, git-rebase

If I start with this history:

```
* 505421e - (HEAD -> stage4) go to stage 4
* 307978f - (stage3) go to stage 3
* d8ab213 - steb b
* 49cbef9 - (stage2) step a
* 6e4a2ed - (stage1) go to stage 1
* 3ca2d7d - do something
* 5ce596d - (stage0) go to stage 0
* 0c8487b - foo
* ccfb7c9 - bar
```

And I do `git rebase -i ccfb7c9` in order to change the `foo` commit, then branches `stage0–stage3` will no longer have the same commit history as `stage4`, and will not have the updated `foo` commit. How do I get them to have the same history?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45844847/6309 looks promising.

Comment: Note in general that preserving the structure is impossible: what if you squashed 3ca2 into 5ce5, for example?  Where should `stage0` point after that?

Comment: @DavisHerring: I think the logically-correct answer is to handle this the same way `git filter-branch` does: make a map of old=>new commit hashes, and replace labels based on the map entries. Squashing two commits means that both old commits map to one new commit. Splitting a commit maps the old commit to the first of the new commits. The existing rebase code doesn't help making these maps though.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  Unfortunately, there is nothing built in to Git to do this the "right way".  It's somewhat difficult to *define* "right" here, although I have a particular definition in mind<sup>1</sup> and started writing a program to do it at one point.  It got too difficult for all the weird corner cases, and I abandoned it.

The fundamental problem here is that `git rebase` works by *copying* commits, as if by `git cherry-pick` (with interactive rebase letting you make some additional changes along the way).<sup>2</sup>  The new copies have new, different hash IDs.<sup>3</sup>  Once the copies are made, Git re-points *one* branch name—the *current* branch, whatever that was when you started the `git rebase`—to the last such copied commit.

In other words, in this case, you have Git copy:

- `0c8487b - foo`
- `5ce596d - (stage0) go to stage 0`
- `3ca2d7d - do something`
- ...
- `505421e - (HEAD -> stage4) go to stage 4`

in that order (earliest to latest), one at a time.  At the first step you make *some* change—it doesn't really matter what, as long as you change something—so that the new commit gets some new, different hash ID, such as `cccccc1` (probably not actually that, but this lets us refer to it as "new commit 1").  The parent commit of this new commit is `ccfb7c9` which is the commit labeled `bar`, so the new history rejoins the old history at that point.

Then Git copies the second commit, `5ce596d - (stage0) go to stage 0`, which becomes, say, `cccccc2`.  The parent of `cccccc2` is `cccccc1`, which alone is sufficiently different from `5ce596d` to force this to be a different commit.  Git goes on to copy all eight commits, with the last one becoming `cccccc8` perhaps; and then Git changes the name `stage4` so that it names commit `cccccc8`.

Thus, when you now look at the history by starting from the commit that Git finds by the name `stage4`, you see the *new* history.  But Git hasn't changed any of the *other* names: `stage3`, for instance, still identifies commit `307978f`, while `stage0` still identifies commit `5ce596d`.  So if you look at your history by starting from any of *those* names, you see the original series of commits.

What you need is to get Git to move each label from its original hash to its new hash.  The problem comes about with identifying all of these things: which labels *should* move?  (You might want some to retain the old commits on purpose, and some to move.)  For that matter, which commit is the correct new commit?  What if, during the interactive rebase, I choose to split some commits and combine others?

The simple and brute-force solution is to manually force any names you want changed, to point to the new commits.  Run `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` and note down the old and new commit IDs for each name, then run:

```
git branch -f stage0 newhash0
git branch -f stage1 newhash1
git branch -f stage2 newhash2
git branch -f stage3 newhash3
```

and you're done.  Or, just delete some of those branch names entirely, since you can find the commits by starting from `stage4` (which moved automatically) and working backwards.

---

<sup>1</sup>The definition I like involves structuring branch names, so that a name has more semantics than just "raw pointer to a commit".  The *form* of this structuring is difficult as well: should it use a name hierarchy, or should we have `git config` entries to groups branch names into "superbranches"?

<sup>2</sup>Some `git rebase` commands literally run `git cherry-pick` and some do not.  Interactive rebase is one of the cases that really does run `git cherry-pick`, along with `git commit --amend` and other tricky items.

<sup>3</sup>The hash ID of any Git object is strictly determined by its contents, so if the "copy" is 100% identical to the original—bit for bit identical—you wind up with the same hash ID, i.e., you simply re-use the original.  But as soon as you make any change at all, the hash ID of some commit in the sequence changes, which forces every "downstream" (child) commit to have a different *parent* hash ID, which changes every downstream commit as well.