# Rebasing a development tree in git

Tags: git

As part of my development process in git I tend to end up with an epic branch and story branches hanging off it:

```
<master>...<epic>...<story>
```

If master gets updated I rebase epic against master and then do the following sequence to rebase story:

```
git log epic..story
<sha> story commit
...
git checkout epic
git checkout -b temp
git cherry-pick <sha>
git branch -D story
git branch -m story
```

So my question is, is there a simpler (more concise) way of carrying out the above sequence?

Comment: Why not rebase `story` to sit ontop of `epic`?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you're on linux you can easily put them in a bash script. Or even on Windows. I think git for Windows has a bash too.

Comment: @NilsWerner I've tried that but for some reason it fails because `epic` has been rebased

Comment: What exactly does it say?

Comment: Well what happens is by rebasing epic the sha of the epic commit changes so if I rebase story it tries to add the original epic commit to epic and ends up in a massive conflict. That's why I ended up doing it the way described.

Comment: [Git rebase subtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504029/git-rebase-subtree) seems to do what you're asking for.

Comment: @NilsWerner Thanks, that's what I'm after. Hadn't rebase --onto