# Merging/Rebasing changes into the parent branch to keep all topic branches up-to-date

Tags: git

**UPDATE**

This answers my question:
[Rebasing a branch including all its children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600659/rebasing-a-branch-including-all-its-children)

**Original question below**

Consider the following log graph:

```
A---B---C origin/master
         \
          D---E---F master
                  \
                  \ E---F topic1
                    G---H---I topic2
```

As shown, I have a master, on which I did some work. I also started to work on 2 topic, after commit F on master.

At this point, I decide I'd like to fetch the recent updates `git fetch` and now my graph looks like that:

```
A---B---C---1---2---3 origin/master
         \
          D---E---F master
                  \
                  \ E---F topic1
                    G---H---I topic2
```

I'd like to merge/rebase all those new changes to both master, topic1, and topic2 in the most painless way (since I am really just trying to keep them up-to-date). It should look like so:

```
A---B---C---1---2---3 origin/master
                     \
                      D---E---F master
                              \
                              \ E---F topic1
                                G---H---I topic2
```

What should I be doing? The way I see is doing

```
$git checkout master
$git rebase origin/master
$git checkout topic1
$git rebase master
$git checkout topic2
$git rebase master
```

Is there a simpler way to do it? It seems to be like quite a common task.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318161/can-git-pull-all-update-all-my-local-branches

Comment: Not exactly the same. But... The gist of it, as I understand, is that there is no simpler way to do it, except batch/scripts?

Comment: This actually seems to answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600659/rebasing-a-branch-including-all-its-children Will check and use it to answer if it does.