# Git: maintaining many topic branches on a frequently-moving base

Tags: git

In my day-to-day git workflow, I have many topic branches, like so:

```
              o--o--o (t2)
             /
         o--o (t1)
        /
 o--o--o (master)
        \
         o--o--o (t3)
```

When I pull from upstream,

```
              o--o--o (t2)
             /
         o--o (t1)
        /
 o--o--o--n--n--n (master)
        \
         o--o--o (t3)
```

I want to **rebase** all my topic branches on top of the new master:

```
                        o'--o'--o' (t2)
                       /
                  o'--o' (t1)
                 /
 o--o--o--n--n--n (master)
                 \
                  o'--o'--o' (t3)
```

Currently I do this by hand, using `git rebase --onto`. In this scenario, the whole update process would be:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git pull
$ git rebase master t1
$ git rebase --onto t1 t2~3 t2
$ git rebase master t3
```

This gets even hairier when jumping between various topic branches and adding commits.

Dependencies between topic branches in my case are purely tree-like: no branch depends on more than a single other branch. (I have to eventually upstream dependent patches in some particular order, so I choose that order a priori.)

Are there any tools that can help me manage this workflow? I've seen [TopGit](http://repo.or.cz/w/topgit.git?a=blob;f=README), but it seems to be tied quite heavily to the `tg patch` email-based workflow, which isn't relevant to me.

Comment: Why are you rebasing `t2` onto `master` instead of just rebasing it onto `t1`, as you show in your graph? Similarly, with `t3`, the `--onto` flag isn't appropriate.

Comment: Also see the question [git rebase branch with all subbranches](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2730866/112968)

Comment: Kevin: whoops, yes -- typo :)

Comment: See also: https://github.com/goncalopp/git-utilities

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pretty much the same question was asked on the git mailing list:
[Rebasing Multiple branches at once...](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/98381/focus=98442)
The linked response has a perl script attached that generates the commands you would need.

If you want this script to be fast and avoid having it tread on your toes, also consider using `git-new-workdir` to set up a working copy just for automatic rebasing.

If you find yourself resolving the same conflicts over and over, consider enabling [git rerere](http://progit.org/2010/03/08/rerere.html).

Having said all that, here is an alternate recipe:

```
# Construct a placeholder commit that has all topics as parent.
HEADS="$(git for-each-ref refs/heads/\*)" &&
MAGIC_COMMIT=$(echo "Magic Octopus"$'\n\n'"$HEADS" |
  git commit-tree \
    $(git merge-base $(echo "$HEADS" | sed 's/ .*//' ))^{tree} \
    $(echo "$HEADS" | sed 's/ .*//;s/^/-p /')) &&
git update-ref refs/hidden/all $MAGIC_COMMIT

# Rebase the whole lot at once.
git rebase --preserve-merges master refs/hidden/all

# Resolve conflicts and all that jazz.

# Update topic refs from the rebased placeholder.
PARENT=
echo "$HEADS" |
while read HASH TYPE REF
do
  let ++PARENT
  git update-ref -m 'Mass rebase' "$REF" refs/hidden/all^$PARENT "$HASH"
done
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! :D I used a slightly modified version of this technique to make a script that rebases just a subtree: https://github.com/nornagon/git-rebase-all

Comment: Note that since Git 2.18, `git rebase` now has `--rebase-merges`, which is an improved version of `--preserve-merges` and should generally be used in its place.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new tool that allows to automate such tasks: [git-assembler](https://www.thregr.org/%7Ewavexx/software/git-assembler/)

Here's a direct link to the example in the documentation for [rebasing local branches](https://www.thregr.org/%7Ewavexx/software/git-assembler/#rebasing-local-branches)

You shouldn't dismiss [TopGit](https://github.com/mackyle/topgit) immediately though. The ability to generate email patches is entirely optional.

Answer (score -4):

Don't rebase. Start your features from a common point. Merges are way less work in the end.

This is what we do:

http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

Comment: That's nice, but I'm integrating with the Chromium workflow, which is linear. These topic branches are local only, small (typically 1-5 commits each) and short-lived.

Comment: Wow, this was a good article to read. +1

Sensible advice about rebasing as well, although there will be reasons to do so in specific circumstances.

Comment: @nornagon in the workflow I have outlined, it applies to small features. There is no difference. Merging is better in general as you will take into consideration code changes and where they came from including moving files.