# How to inject a commit between some two arbitrary commits in the past when there is multiple branch above?

Tags: git, git-rebase

The question is an extension of this one: [How to inject a commit between some two arbitrary commits in the past?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315156/how-to-inject-a-commit-between-some-two-arbitrary-commits-in-the-past)

Suppose I have the following commit history on my local-only branch:

```
A -- B -- C -- D  
            \- E
```

How do I insert a new commit between A and B and keep both D and E above C?

Comment: Have you tried the answers to that question?

Comment: yes, in the answer I need to choose what branch (let say E or D) I want to rebase on A. But I want to rebase D and E at the same time, to avoid breaking the two branches and keep the common C. I know I can choose E and rebase -i on A, and then rebase --onto to add the E branches on C, but when there is lot of above branches, it's a lot of work.

Comment: Yes, it is a lot of work because git does not directly support this kind of workflow.

Comment: I thought git allow history rewritting to have a clean project. So this is only true when I am on a single branch? after diverging there is no way to easily alter the history?

Comment: Your solution is to use `git replace` and then `git filter-branch` (but hash of all the commits after A will change)

Comment: git replace may solve the problem, but the goal here is to have a clean history that may be transferable to other project. I'm a bit afraid of the mess of replace. I Will try anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) on your first branch to inject your commit and then do a [rebase onto](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) to apply this changes to your other branch.

Assuming you have:

```
A -- B -- C -- D  
           \-- E
```

After injecting your commit into your first branch (following the [How to inject a commit between some two arbitrary commits in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315156/how-to-inject-a-commit-between-some-two-arbitrary-commits-in-the-past)) you would have something like:

```
A -- A2 -- B' -- C' -- D'
 \-- B  -- C  -- E
```

Than you can do a `rebase --onto` from your another branch, to apply the changes it:

> git rebase --onto C' E branch2

So you final result would be:

```
A -- A2 -- B' -- C' -- D'
                   \-- E'
```

Comment: To better understand `rebase --onto` you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29914052/10657880).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but as I said in this comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53584752/how-to-inject-a-commit-between-some-two-arbitrary-commits-in-the-past-when-there/53585114#comment94033440_53584752 I know this solution, but it can be a huge work if there is lot of branches above C. I'm looking for a solution that does the same, but whithout the "104 branches, 104 rebase to do". Maybe the only solution is scripting.

Comment: Have you seen [How can I rebase multiple branches at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23386318/10657880)? There are some utilities made for this purpose.

Comment: thanks, that's may be a solution, but I can't manage to make it work. Assertion failed, some name are undefined. May be it's an unfinished work.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the madness :) and just add the commit to `D` and then either `merge` or `cherry-pick` it to `E`

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- X 
           \-- E -- X
```

Comment: Yes I now that your solution is the productive one, where I can go back to work after two cherry-pick. But what if the ABC commit are common to hundreds of branches?can't I extend the ABC root to ABB'C in one operation?

Comment: Yes it's true, but what if there is 23 branches aboce C?

Comment: ...than it's even more risky to do it before C. How would you test a change in 23 branches?

Comment: Ok I agree that seem to be a bad idea. But in this precise case I try to insert a commit that does an add in the makefile, and I want this new little feature everywhere when I crusing my history. But in a more general situation the intergration test are here for that, right?