# Rebase multiple branches into master with one command

Tags: git, git-branch, git-rebase

I am working on some abandoned repo that has two dozen feature branches, and I want them in master, is there a way to rebase then all in one command or do I have to do them one by one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I rebase multiple branches at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386318/how-can-i-rebase-multiple-branches-at-once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do merge in one command:

```
# providing the current branch is `master`
git merge br1 br2 br3
```

As for rebase, it very much depends on what you mean by "one command". Is the following one command?

```
for br in br1 br2 br3; do git rebase master $br; done
```

Comment: We can probably argue to decide if it is "one command" or "one liner" but that would be off-topic as "opinion based" :D