# How to pull updates from master in a nested branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

I use Git flow and currently I'm implementing 2 features, so my branches look like this:

```
master     A------------------
            \                 
develop      B-----------     
                 \    \
feature1          \    C------
                   \
feature2            D---------
```

Recently there was a hot fix (A1) and I rebased develop branch to that commit

```
master     A-----------------A1
            \                 \
develop      B-----------      B1------
                 \    \
feature1          \    C------
                   \
feature2            D------
```

But how do I get that master update in features branches?

Comment: `git rebase -–update-refs` See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6489904/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rebase+dependent+branch

Comment: You said you use Git flow. I doubt that Git flow rebases the development branch.

Answer (score 1):

This is done with

```
for branch in feature1 feature2; do git rebase B $branch --onto develop; done
```

Then you get:

```
A-----------------A1 (master)
                   \
                    B' (develop)
                     \
                      --- C' (feature1)
                       \
                        --- D' (feature2)
```